# Reverse the order of elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$names = array('joey','kaiba','marik','yugi');
```

I want to reverse the order of the elements inside this array that would look something like this:

```
$names = array('yugi','marik','kaiba','joey');
```

Is there an existing PHP function that would allow me to do this?

Comment: You're looking for [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Np :) Please mark one of the answers on your question as answered so your question doesn't remain unanswered forever :)

Comment: Try Google or the PHP site first in the future. Google your sentence `reverse the order of the elements inside this array` with  `php` and you the first result is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP function [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) does exactly what you're looking for:

```
$names = array('joey','kaiba','marik','yugi');
$reversed = array_reverse($names);

print_r($reversed);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => yugi
    [1] => marik
    [2] => kaiba
    [3] => joey
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a inbuilt function that php provide is array_reverse()

```
<?php

$names = array('joey','kaiba','marik','yugi');
print_r(array_reverse($names));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = array('joey','kaiba','marik','yugi');
$names=array_reverse($names);
```

Comment: You should always include some sort of write up with an answer.